# Regex to capture every bit between delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture all groups in a URL between given delimiters (slashes), but can't seem to find a solution since full match always includes the delimiters.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/**captureme**/**capturemetoo**/**capturemeaswell**/notme.php
```

If I use a simple regex such as `#\/(.*?)\/#` I get matches for "captureme" and "capturemeaswell" but am missing "capturemetoo".

The difficulty is that the length of blocks to catch can vary, for instance we could also have:

```
http://www.example.com/group1/group2/group3/group4/group5/page.php
```

Where every group would need to be captured.

Comment: I‘d rather use `parse_url` to get the path, and then simply explode that at the slashes ...

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? For this, I might use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` together with `explode()` and maybe `dirname()`

Comment: if looking for a general solution (parse_url indeed better for that case), you have lookarounds that can be used to match a group without consuming it, in your case `#\/(.*?)(?=\/)#`. `?=` is for a positive lookahead. Note that you will capture the blank between the first two slashes in `http://` as a first result though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the following way

```
$re = '/([^\/]+\/)/';
$str = 
'http://www.example.com/group1/group2/group3/group4/group5/page.php';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
// pop the first 2 matches
var_dump(array_slice($matches,2));
```

it would match the http and domain but that can be removed using slice

see it in the [online compiler](https://ideone.com/8BxZSp)

Comment: +1 for keeping with the regex constraint. However, based on suggestions from CBroe and Michael Berkowsi, I think I'll go the parse_url() and explode() php builtin functions